# Filter thumbnail gallery with lightbox functionality

Tags: html, css, filter, zurb-foundation, image-gallery

I am new to HTML, CSS and JS.

I've managed to create the bulk of my first site but I am having a lot of issues with my responsive filter image gallery. I am using Foundation Clearing with a plugin filter. Here's my issue:

When I click on a specific filter and try to scroll through this one filters images, the order in which they display in the clearing reverts back to the order of the 'all' filter. Meaning that images not under this filter still display regardless.

How do I make sure the clearing only displays the relevant images for the specific filter selected?

here's the site URL: http://www.clairenolan.ie

Really hoping someone can advise me on this as it's driving me nuts! Thanks! :)

Comment: All images seem to be broken and makes it harder to understand the problem. Fix image urls if you can.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I had a small mistake in each of the image links. It's fixed now though http://www.clairenolan.ie Would really appreciate if you could offer on help on this still. Thanks, Mark

Comment: Filters seems to work property, can you give an example with a specific photo? or a way to recreate to problem

Comment: @user3127632 Hey, yep the filter as itself, works great. It's just the lighbox which is the problem. I've put together a quick pdf which explains the issue more clearly if that helps? It's uploaded here http://uploadpie.com/vgftP